# How can I rasterize a shapefile with C/C++ using GDAL?

Tags: c, gdal

I want to rasterize a shapefile in C or C++ using GDAL.
But the GDAL documentation is not explicit enough for me.
Does someone have a code sample, useful links or advice on how to do it properly?

Thanks.

This is the code I'm try to use but get error GDALRasterize(filename1,NULL,lineDS_shp, NULL,NULL)

```
GDALAllRegister();
char filename1[]="./datas/myRaster.tiff";
char filename3[]="./datas/janze_montlouis_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif";
char filename2[]="./datas/ExportPolylignes_lines.shp";
GDALDatasetH lineDS,lineDS_shp;
lineDS_shp = GDALOpenEx(filename2, GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL, NULL 
);
lineDS = GDALRasterize(filename1,NULL,lineDS_shp,NULL,NULL);
GDALClose(lineDS_shp);
GDALClose(lineDS);
```

ERROR 1: Size and resolutions are missing

Process finished with exit code 0